# anchor click to download not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var anchor = angular.element('<a/>');
anchor.attr({
    href: 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(response.data),
    target: '_blank',
    download: 'Rates.csv'
})[0].click();
```

This anchor element doesn't work in firefox and internet explorer, but works in Chrome. Is it because I never add the element to the DOM? How do I fix this?

This is to get the rates from the server and display as an attachment to download.

UPDATE:

```
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.href = 'data:attachment/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(response.data);
anchor.target = '_blank';
anchor.download = 'Rates.csv';
document.body.appendChild(anchor);
anchor.click();
$timeout(function () {
   anchor.remove();
}, 50);
```

Added this in my directive, and it is working fine now.

Comment: Add it to the DOM, fire click, delete it from the DOM ...!?

Comment: works in firefox, but not in edge... any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`click()` works for Chrome. For Firefox, you can try below code

```
 var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
 ev.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, self, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);

// Fire event
anchor.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with Angular that much, but if the download property that you are passing to the attr() method represents the HTML5 download attribute, your problem is that this is not fully supported in all browsers yet.